# Dataframe replace false positive values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with columns Name and Level. Level has 2 values : On and Off. For some indices of dataframe there appears false positives. For example:

```
Timestamp    CompName  Level
----------------------------
2021-09-07   B.        Off
2021-09-08   B.        Off
2021-09-09   B.        Off
2021-09-10   B.        On
2021-09-11   B.        Off
```

Between hundreds of "Off" values some 1-2 "On" values appear which are false positives and I want to replace them with "Off" to make it normal. Or in other cases, it is vice versa

```
 Timestamp     CompName  Level
 ----------------------------
 2021-09-07   A.          On
 2021-09-08   A.          On
 2021-09-09   A.          On
 2021-09-10   A.          Off
 2021-09-11   A.          On
```

This time For different component name there appears single Level value "off" between "On" values and this time I want it to be replaced by "on".

But if the value is the first row for each component names i do not want it to be replaced. For example:

```
 Timestamp     CompName   Level
 ------------------------------
 2021-09-07     C.          On
 2021-09-08     C.          Off
 2021-09-09     C.          Off
 2021-09-10     C.          Off
 2021-09-11     C.          Off
```

Now the value On should not be replaced because it is the first value for compname C.

How can I achieve it?

I have tried iterating over indices and replace it but it does not give me the result I wanted

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
most_common_value = df['Level'].value_counts().index[0]
df['Level'].iloc[1:] = most_common_value
```

Output:

```py
>>> df
Timestamp    CompName  Level
2021-09-07   B.        On
2021-09-08   B.        Off
2021-09-09   B.        Off
2021-09-10   B.        On
2021-09-11   B.        Off

>>> most_common_value = df['Level'].value_counts().index[0]
>>> df['Level'].iloc[1:] = most_common_value
>>> df
    Timestamp CompName Level
0  2021-09-07       B.    On
1  2021-09-08       B.   Off
2  2021-09-09       B.   Off
3  2021-09-10       B.   Off
4  2021-09-11       B.   Off

>>> most_common_value
'Off'
```